# How to open a checkboxlist while selecting a dropdownitem.?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I have a text box, dropdownlist and a checkboxlist.  Now I want the checkboxlist to display when I select the dropdown item.  The list in the checkboxlist will depend on the item which I'm selecting from the dropdownlist.

Comment: You may hide/show checkboxlist by setting Visible property of CheckboxList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Dropdownlist selected index changed event for your selection changes.as well as checked list box Visible.

Code Behind:

```
 Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 1 Then
            CheckBoxList1.Visible = True
            If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
                'Put Your Code Here
            Else
                'Put Your Code Here
            End If
        Else
            CheckBoxList1.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CheckBoxList1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

Design:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="256px" AutoPostBack="true"OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

Comment: In the DropDownList markup add OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" so that the event handler is registered with the control

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Since it seems you have not yet discovered how to accept answers.